# How to create parallel offset lines in 3D space

Tags: geometry, 3d, python

I'm working with a $~3$D visualization toolkit in python.I want to draw lines  (which will be converted to tubes) between given $~3$D points. I have a function that given two $~3$D points $~(P1(X,Y,Z), ~~P2(X,Y,Z))~$ draws a line between them and converted to a tube.

However, in some cases I need to convert the line to two offset parallel lines with small distance between them. Thus I need to calculate the new points for the two lines $~(P1',P1'', P2' and P2'')~$.

This following image summarizes the starting point and the desired result :

[image]

Comment: Note that this task is ill-posed, since there are infinitely many pairs of smaller cylinders you could draw (by rotating the pair around the axis of the original cylinder). Do you have more information about *exactly* how you want to draw the two small cylinders?

Comment: From the picture it looks like all points belong to the same plane, and new points should also belong to that plane. Is it so?

Comment: @user7530, the two small cylinders needs to be parallel to each other. The radius of the cylinders is not important (e.g. half as the original tube is good). The distance between the two new tubes needs to be constant.

Comment: @Aretino, For a single tube that's true. But there are cases where the whole objects' points belong to different planes.But each tube (two points) can be treated individually. Thus, a formula to convert one tube (two 3D points) to two parallel offset tubes (two 3D points for each tube) will also work. Thanks

Comment: As mentioned before, you need to mention the plane where the axes of the two cylinders lie. Let's suppose you draw the pentagon on the piece of paper. Are the new cylinders on the paper, or can you separate them such that one is above the plane and one below?

Comment: @Andrei, The new tubes are on the paper.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the new tubes to be in a particular plane, I would approach the problem as follows:

- We need to describe the plane. The easy way is to use 3 points, $P_1$, $P_2$ and an additional $P_3$, not on the $P_1P_2$ line.
- Next step is to find a vector in the plane, perpendicular to $P_2-P_1$. You can write this using the dot product:
  $$\begin{align}\vec a&=P_2-P_1\\\vec b&=P_3-P_1\\\vec b_{||}&=\vec a(\vec b\cdot\vec a)/|\vec a|^2\\\vec b_\perp&=\vec b-\vec b_\perp\\\hat b_\perp&=\vec b_\perp/|\vec b_\perp|\end{align}$$
- If the distance between the new tubes is $d$, write the new positions of the ends of the tubes as$$P_{1,2}^{',''}=P_{1,2}\pm\frac d2 \hat b_\perp$$